# Merge all separated lines with connecting extremities into single continuous lines

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector

I got a DWG file from a friend that contains the curve lines of an area. However, once I import the file and then convert it to shapefile, all the lines are split. I would like to connect all the split lines whose end points connect into a single continuous line. There aren't any attribute to be maintained, my objective is purely geometrical. Since I have many lines, I cannot do it by selecting manually the segments and then merge them with Merge Features, I need to find an automatic way of doing.

[image]

I tried using the **MergeLines** plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QGISMergeLines-master/) in QGIS 2.18 (it only works for QGIS < 3.0), but the merging result is incomplete. I thought of using **Shapely** but I am still a novice in Python, so I am not sure if I would be able to do it.

[image]
*The lines are complete separate before using **MergeLines** (QGIS 2.18)*

[image]
*Some have merged but not all after using **MergeLines** (QGIS 2.18)*

The lines do not posses any attributes, such as the elevation, that could help me merge them with the tool **Dissolve**. Also, the lines aren't grouped under a multiline geometry. They are separate entities. I know that the **Merge Lines** (in QGIS 3) works with multiline geometries, which unfortunately isn't my case

Comment: What about the "Merge Lines" processing in Qgis 3 ? It should merge the connected multilines in one line.

Comment: If there's an elevation attribute attached to the lines, you can `dissolve` based on it.

Comment: Hi, there isn't. I was planning on assigning manually the elevation attribute to the merged lines. Actually, my sole purpose is to assign them an elevation attribute, and to make it easier, I would like to merge all the segments beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Do the lines have an attribute in CAD? Maybe you know someone who can export the DWG to shape using the spatial manager?